# Cant login to ubuntu 16.04 (this is fifth time in last week)

Tags: 16.04

I am on mobile.

This is fifth time. I reinstalled four times.

Please look at my recent questions.

I entet password and it says xxx files xx blocks and keep showing logib screen.

I dont know what caused this.

I installed as usual chrome yakuake zsh notepadqq inteljidea nvidia mysql emma

Changed

etc enviroment
Zshrc
Anthome javahome

Please help me. I dont want to reinstall :( or break my desktop

This is 5. Times happening same thing. I dont know what i am doing to cause.

What i did:

- I removed nvidia, settings but did not work.
- Renamed xauthotiry to see if causing. But not worked
- sudo dkpgreconfigure lightdm
- var log xorg 0 log shows no error. I couksnot find any error or warning there. But maybe i am looking wrong. This is image fron there. Only error is that. Can you look 
  https://pasteboard.co/HpnxnQC.jpg
- This is xsessionerrors 
  https://pasteboard.co/HpnyrRv.jpg
- ls -al , all of them are my user except dbus. It is root. Inside tmp, all of rhem are root. Such as xim unix

  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Dont you see it is different." No, unfortunately not. Saying "I tried everything" is as good as "I tried nothing", neither holds specific information. And your description of the issue with going to a black screen and returning to the login after entering the password perfectly matches that common issue. Anyway, thanks for updating your question so far. Do you have a `~/.xsession-errors` file with any useful messages? Have you checked permissions of your home directory and the /tmp folder?

Comment: Thank you for asking to try to help. I looked xsession and saw those https://pasteboard.co/HpnyrRv.jpg sorry , i am on mobile and cant write so much thing. Photo is easier. At home, i tried from other desktop, it was easier. Now i am at work and i am on panic. For ls -al , all of them are my user except dbus. It is root. Inside tmp, all of rhem are root. Such as xim unix

Comment: @ByteCommander So, should this question be closed as a duplicate now? An [answer regarding modified `/etc/environment`](https://askubuntu.com/a/637661/250300) already exists below the linked question.

Comment: @Melebius Could be, but not necessarily. That post is linked, but as this one is answered well now, it doesn't really matter whether it gets closed or not. I retracted my close vote earlier, but everyone may form their own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045550/cant-login-to-ubuntu-16-04-this-is-fifth-time-im-last-week#comment1705074_1045550),
I found the error.

In my `/etc/environment`
I had added `export` parts:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant"

export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I removed export paths and it worked.

I think I should put `/` to end of them. I am not sure about it. And I don’t know how can I be sure after again adding them.

I removed `export` parts

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384301/9103745

like that

```
  JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171"
     ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant"

     PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
     PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

but it did not work.

**UPDATE**

This is my `.profile` , lastversion:

```
 ...
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

    PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

this is `etc/enviroment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171"
ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant"
```

and for `.zshrc`
i added those to bottom

```
     source /etc/environment
  source ~/.profile
```

Now it seems it is working. When i open a new terminal, it will source both. I dont know if this is a good idea but could not find any other way.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Yes, `/etc/environment` may only contain `variable=value` assignments, no shell commands like `export`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thank yo. You gave ideas to look out but it was luck to check that file. I updated my answer. Without export, i tried but again, `xsession` showed same errors (maybe the old errors). COuld not login again. After updating `etc/enviroment`, is there a way to check if it is correct without restarting? I suspended but it did not work.

Comment: Oh, and variable expansions like `$PATH` or `$ANT_HOME` also don't work in `/etc/environment`. You can only set fixed strings there. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: @Byte Commander so, I will define only `Java and Ant` in `/etc/enviroment`. How will i export them for `$PATH`? `.profile`?

Comment: The way you solved it is absolutely fine. I'd have done it the same way. Very nice.